How to resolved the angular 13 version build issue?
Facing an issue building with Angular 13:

I am trying to build using ng build --configuration=test but I'm getting the errors listed above. If I comment the bootstrap.min.css in the Angular json file now its building fine.
What is the issue, and how can I fix it?

You might have not included the bootstrap.min.css file in your build system.
It can be done by importing the file at the top of the root style.css file or by including it in the styles array under the build object in the angular.json file.
In the below snapshot, you can see the styles array. You can include the path to bootstrap.min.css file inside styles array

